# RxAlamofire, как распарсить дату

Tags: json, swift

Я только начал изучать RxSwift.
Не могу разобраться, как мне самым простым способом распарсить данные.

У меня есть модель

```
class Page: Codable {
    
    let info: Info
    let results: [Result]

    init(info: Info, results: [Result]) {
        self.info = info
        self.results = results
    }
}

class Info: Codable {
    
    let count, pages: Int
    let next: String?
    let prev: String?

    init(count: Int, pages: Int, next: String?, prev: String?) {
        self.count = count
        self.pages = pages
        self.next = next
        self.prev = prev
    }
}

class Result: Codable {
    
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let status: String
    let species: String
    let gender: String
    let origin: Origin
    let location: Location
    let image: String
    let episode: [String]
    let url: String
    let created: String
    
    init(id: Int, name: String, status: String, species: String, gender: String, origin: Origin, location: Location, image: String, episode: [String], url: String, created: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.status = status
        self.species = species
        self.gender = gender
        self.origin = origin
        self.location = location
        self.image = image
        self.episode = episode
        self.url = url
        self.created = created
    }
}

class Origin: Codable {
    
    let name, url: String
    
    init(name: String, url: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.url = url
    }
}

class Location: Codable {
    
    let name, url: String
    
    init(name: String, url: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.url = url
    }
}
```

Также есть метод в классе:

```
class CharactersParsing {
    
    let db = DisposeBag()
    var result: [Result] = []
    
    func loadCharacters(){
        RxAlamofire.data(.get, Url.shared.getUrl())
                        .subscribe(onNext: {
                            do {
                                let data = try JSONDecoder().decode(Page.self, from: $0)
                                self.result = data.results // как сделать, чтобы это сработало?
                            } catch {
                                print(error)
                            }
                        })
                        .disposed(by: db)
    }
    
        
}
```

Прилагаю URL:

```
class Url {
    
    static let shared = Url()
    
    var page = 1
    
    func getUrl() -> String {
        "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character?page=\(page)"
    }
}
```

Хочу наполнить переменную result данными.
Подскажите, как это сделать, буду очень благодарен :)

Comment: что именно смущает? Данные успешно приходят и попадают в result

Comment: @schmidt9 нет, данные остаются внутри do catch

Comment: данные успешно присваиваются, просто вы с ними ничего не делаете. Что вы хотите сделать с result после получения? Передать куда то из класса CharactersParsing или использовать внутри этого класса?

Comment: @schmidt9 вынести из класса

Comment: @schmidt9  Внутри подписки через print(result) всё выводится в консоль, а за её пределами нет

Answer (score 1):

Я разобрался, сделал из метода наблюдаемую последовательность.

```
func loadCharacters() -> Observable<[Result]> {
        return RxAlamofire.data(.get, Url.shared.getUrl()).map { response in
            do {
                let data = try JSONDecoder().decode(Page.self, from: response)
                return data.results
            } catch {
                print(error)
                return []
            }
        }.asObservable()
    }
```